# How to parse /proc/cmdline before asking tty login with systemd

Tags: shell, systemd

First, I'm trying to parse `/proc/cmdline` with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat /proc/cmdline)
do
    export $i
done
```

I tried to make a systemd service

```
[Unit]
Description=Parse cmdline

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "source /opt/cmdline_parser.sh"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Starting the service manually works, but vars are not exported in my shell.
I need this to be done as early as possible, to be able to choose starting login or launch a script. So, putting the first script in `/etc/profile.d` is not possible.

kernel parameters i want to test are : 
"deploy package=testxz_9e full bittorrent"

I PXE boot clients on nfsroot, and i want to start the deploy script, if $deploy is setted. The script needs $package to know which archive to deploy, $full means that i will restore and mkfs all partitions, $bittorrent tells to use bittorent to deploy.

I want theses var exported in the shell used by systemd. 
For var without "var=value" syntax, i just want to test them with bash "if [[ -v $var ]]", so i think it's not important if it has no value.

[image: deploy]

Here the PXE boot file :

```
DEFAULT tool
label tool
KERNEL tool_nfs/vmlinuz
APPEND ro initrd=tool_nfs/initrd.img root=/dev/nfs ip=dhcp nfsroot=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/srv/nfsroot web_srv=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx deploy package=testxz_9e full=y bittorrent
```

Comment: Why don't you just start your `deploy.sh` script instead of the indirection with exporting the kernel cmdline options from a shell script (that won't work)? And if you want the service to start before login, use `WantedBy=getty.target`.

Comment: Please only ask a single question per post. I removed your second question, please ask it separately. You can see the deleted text in the [edit history](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/264971/revisions). That said, you don't want to do `for i in $(cat ...)`. This will fails if one of the variables has more than a single value (on my system, for example, I have `root=/dev/sda2 rw`). Please [edit] your question and explain what your final goal is, perhaps we can offer a better way. Make sure to explain what shell you expect the variables to be exported to.

Comment: kba, i can try that, if i understood well : creating a service with WantedBy=getty.target which start a script that test kernel parameters and start the script if there exists. The last problem with this solution is that i dont want to launch tty login if somebody CTRL+C the script. Ok terdon

Comment: So, assuming `/proc/cmdline` contains `deploy package=testxz_9e full bittorrent`, what variable do you want to export and to what shell? Should there be one variable (`package=testxz_9e full` or `package=testxz_9e bittorrent`) or two variables (for example, `package=testxz_9e`, `state=full`)? What shell should have access to them? Your shell after booting? The shell that boots? Please [edit] and explain more clearly. In any case, it won't work with `for i in $(cat ...)`.

Comment: Done, let me know if it's still unclear. Ok for the test with "for i in", i just let it in the thread for posterity

Comment: I modified vars to be set like that : "deploy=bittorrent package=testxz_9e full=y"