# systemd: Move getty to tty2+ and start script on tty1

Tags: systemd, getty, autostart

I'd like to "autorun" a shell script on `tty1` *and* start the rest of the `tty`s on `tty2`, `tty3`, ...

So far I have [followed this advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265014/how-to-start-a-script-on-tty-instead-of-asking-for-login-in-systemd) (besides a ton of googling) and gotten the script to run on `tty1` as root, but then the rest of the login consoles disappear, leaving `tty2`+ empty.

What is the proven and secure way to run a script on `tty1` (maybe even as different user than root?) *and* have the normal `getty`s on `tty2`+?

In case it's of importance this is under Raspian, `systemd` version 215 and Linux 4.9.20.

Comment: did you try to leave getty@tty1.service as it is, and just 'overwrite' tty1 with: `sudo openvt -fc1 /path/to/scriptname`