# Can you run a program before the TTY login shows up?

Tags: systemd, login, tty

I want to execute `cmatrix` in my TTY for when I connect my Raspberry Pi to a monitor by default. I found a .service file [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265075/530642), and I'm wondering if it could work in my case.

Again, I just want `cmatrix` to run automatically on boot before the TTY login, but when I press `q`, the TTY login shows up, and that's about it.

Can the answer linked above work for me before I screw up my system?

Comment: Please post the full script you are using here, if it is not identical to the one in your link as well as the file name and current directory your script is located in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I had same needs with my Raspberry 3B and 3.5" monitor that doesn't go on screen blank.

Create the file

```
/root/loginMatrix.sh
```

and give execute permissions

```
chmod ug+x /root/loginMatrix.sh
```

create the file

```
/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf
```

with the following content

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/root/loginMatrix.sh
StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=tty
```

then activate it

```
systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl restart getty@tty1.service
```

or reboot.

You'll have cmatrix as screen saver, and just press a key to have login prompt. Doing CTRL+D to exit from session and you'll see cmatrix again.

[image]

Comment: I've been searching so long to no avail. Thank you!